# Difference Between Inherited Widget and BLoC?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

**I'm Searching a lot about the Difference between Inherited Widget and Bloc State management**

I found that Inherited Widget is *immutable* but Bloc don't
I know the mutable and Immutable concept well but I just want to ask

**Why inherited widget is Immutable and what difference between it and Bloc ?**

Answer (score 2):

Bloc and inheritedWidget are very different things.

Bloc is component that takes events as an input, react to this event and yields state through stream. Widgets then can listen to this stream of events and rebuild when new pierce of data is available. Bloc Is independent of widgets that listen to it, or insert events.

Inherited Widget just provides piece of data down to all his children. You have access to this data through buildContext. Also you can notify inherited Widget that Its data changed, which will result in rebuilding all widgets under it.

Comment: Okay got it , But i have 2 questions 
1- if the sub child of the inherited widget does depend on data of the inherited widget 
when inherited rebuild cause data changed . . will this child of nondependant data rebuild too ?

Comment: 2nd question, so What's difference between provider and inherited widget?

Comment: 1, As far as i know whole tree down the inherited widget will be rebuilded. 
2, Provider is just a wrapper around inherited widget, so it is more convenient to work with it.

Comment: so what's addition feature in provider than inherited widget?

Comment: You can check out their pub.dev package. https://pub.dev/packages/provider All info that it provides over inherited widget is there.